# How to make a list of DDL in C# programatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, drop-down-menu

I would like to know the way to make a list of drop down lists in C# class. I have been trying like this:

```
List<DropDownList> _ddlCollection;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                _ddlCollection.Add(new DropDownList());
            }
```

Then I add _ddlCollection to the Asp.NET site like this:

```
 foreach (DropDownList ddl in _ddlCollection)
    {
        this.Controls.Add(ddl);
    }
```

But it breaks on line:

```
_ddlCollection.Add(new DropDownList());
```

Can you tell me how to add a few DDL's to a List?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It "breaks" because you haven't initialized the local variable `_ddlCollection` here:

```
List<DropDownList> _ddlCollection;
// you cannot use _ddlCollection until it's initialized, 
// it would compile if you'd "initialize" it with null, 
// but then it would fail on runtime
```

> A local variable introduced by a local-variable-declaration is not
>   automatically initialized and thus **has no default value**. Such a local
>   variable is considered initially unassigned. A local-variable-declaration can include a local-variable-initializer, in which case the variable is considered definitely assigned in its entire scope, except within the expression provided in the local-variable-initializer..

[**Local variables**](http://en.csharp-online.net/ECMA-334%3a_12.1.7_Local_variables)

This is a correct initialization:

```
List<DropDownList> _ddlCollection = new List<DropDownList>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have not initialized `_ddlCollection`, therefore when you `.Add` it breaks.

You need to assign `_ddlCollection` an instance of `List<DropDownList>`.

```
 _ddlCollection = new List<DropDownList>();
```